# how to get current location in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, geolocation

i  added Geolocation plugin in my app and used this code for getting the current location in phonegap. but this code does not work.

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("4");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

function onSuccess(position) {
    alert("1");
}

function onError(error) {
    alert("3");
}
```

Where is the problem in my code?

thank you and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Add more information like what error you are getting? see error in eclipse logcat. And also try this

`var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);`
Does alert '4' fire?

Comment: alert("4") is fire. but next line is not work.
and no error. :'(

Comment: suggestion: 1. check if geolocation is properly installed or not? 2. restart your phone(silly solution but it works sometimes) 3. check if your geo permissions & settings are turned on in device 4. test with the code that I put on comment 5. If you're using android, try to get the error with eclipse logcat.

Comment: Thank you my friend.
i reset my phone and work this code.
thank you for your help. :)

Comment: haha :P welcome I faced that issue a long ago. It's kind of funny. Let me give you those suggestions as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. check if geolocation is properly installed or not
2. restart your phone (silly solution but it works sometimes.I faced it once)
3. check if your geo permissions & settings are turned on in device
4. test with this code

   `options = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);`
5. If you're using android, try to get the error with eclipse logcat.

Answer (score 6):

On iOS this will always work one way or the other. If the plugin fails, the browser's own Geolocation API will be used. There's some undesired side effects with the fallback though:

- The permission dialog that pop's up has the html file's name in the title instead of the app name
- Granted permissions will only persist as long as the app is running

On Android it only works if you have set the correct permissions in app/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Comment: ""On Android it only works if you have set the correct permissions in app/AndroidManifest.xml:"" This helped me to nail down geolocation,  reverse geolocation problem in my case.