# Phonegap Add pin points or positions to map to map

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a app in phone gap which show my current location but i want to add some points to or location like near by hotel, Cinema hall am not able to add

JS Code for map api

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { timeout: 30000 });
function onSuccess(position) {
var lat=position.coords.latitude;
var lang=position.coords.longitude;

//Google Maps
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lang);
var mapOptions = {zoom: 13,center: myLatlng}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng,map: map});
}
function onError(error) {
alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', onSuccess);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25010981/4008711).
2. Chrome doesn't support geolocation without a security origin. [read more](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only)
3. If you need help again, you can put your code in codepen, jsfiddle to help in understanding.
4. You can see your code running [here](https://s.codepen.io/thulioph/debug/PzdQBL).

I hope help you!